# vb.net login with sqlite

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

im trying to create a login form in vb.net with SQLite with this code

```
Imports System.Data.SQLite

Public Class frmLogin


    Private Sub btnlogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click

        Dim table As DataTable = Nothing
        Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter("Select * from user_tbl where username='" & txtuser.Text & "'and pass_id='" & txtpass.Text & "'", myconn)
        Try
            If txtuser.Text = "" And txtpass.Text = "" Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill Username and Password", "Important", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                txtuser.Focus()

            Else
                da.Fill(table)
                If table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    frmMain.Show()
                    Me.Close()
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("login not successful")
                End If

                da.Dispose()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmLogin_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ConnectME()
    End Sub
End Class
```

but i keep getting an error at line 26 "da.fill(table)"

Here is what the error says:

[image]

Comment: The only right way to do build SQL is using SQL parameters.  Building it like that can result in many problems from SQL injection attacks, data type mismatch, formatting issues and errors from names like `O'Brien`.  Also, passwords should never ever be stored as plain text.  It is also not wise to use one connection and leave it open for the life of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two lines of your code:

```
Dim table As DataTable = Nothing

da.Fill(table)
```

You have no code in between that assigns an object to that `table` variable.  Why exactly are you surprised that there's an issue here?  If I told you to fill a bag and then handed you no bag, how exactly would you go about filling it?  You couldn't, because you can't fill a bag that doesn't exist, yet you expect your app to be able to fill a `DataTable` that doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry bout that actually remove the "= Nothing " but I still get the same Problem

Comment: Removing that doesn't help. A variable is still `Nothing` by default. If you don't assign a `DataTable` to that variable then it doesn't refer to a `DataTable`. I have to wonder how many examples of the use of a data adapter you've looked at if you haven't seen a `DataTable` created. I just Binged "vb.net fill datatable" and the very first match was an SO thread that includes in the code of the accepted answer the creation and population of a `DataTable`. I would consider a search like that to be the most basic of research.